# How to point a menu link at a View with multiple options on the same exposed filter selected?

Tags: views, uri

I've got a view page that serves like a catalog, using many exposed filters.

I want a menu link that points to a certain combination of filters. Let's say the URL for this filtered view is>

> view?option[]=7&option[]=12&option[]=14

Sounds simple, but I'm finding this difficult for a number of reasons:

- Menu considers this an invalid path
- I can't turn it into a path alias, because that also considers it an invalid path
- I can set it up as a redirect, but Menu still won't recognise the redirect as a valid path
- I can set it up as a Page Manager page using cTools' page manager, and set that to act as a redirect, but every parameter except the last one gets chopped and it redirects to this. It seems like it doesn't like the ampersands:

> view?option[]=14

- If I input it with the ampersands URL encoded, it gets confused because it double URL encodes the URL encoded characters, breaking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I set it up as a Page Manager page with an arbitrary path (e.g. `options` or `view/options`), set to "HTTP Response Code" then "301 redirect".

The problem in the question where the ampersand-seperated characters were getting eaten seemed to be caused by Drupal treating them as duplicates of each other and rejecting all except the last. To get around that, I set the redirect URL to:

> view?option[1]=7&option[2]=12&option[3]=14

Note how each one has a unique number in the square brackets.

Views doesn't seem to care about the numbers in the square brackets, and they stop Drupal merging the parameters into one.

---

Note you should always input the non-encoded version, like above, else Drupal will double-encode it causing it to break. Keep this in mind if you edit it - you'll need to replace the whole string with the original, non-encoded version then edit that before saving.

Comment: I was able to use your solution of adding unique ids inside the square brackets to add multiple exposed filters to a url in the menu directly - eg view?option[1]=7&option[2]=12&option[3]=14